# JetBrains Rider "Use mono-service to start service processes" on Debian Jessie

Tags: c#, mono, rider

I recently installed Rider 1.0 EAP, and I'm unable run a Visual Studio project in .NET 4.5. Load and build functionality works, but when I try to run the project I get the message: "Use mono-service to start service processes".

The line being executed to attempt starting the process is:

```
/usr/bin/mono /path/FileName.exe
```

I've looked for a location in Rider to reconfigure mono to mono-service, but have not found a way to do this...

I also attempted to load the process with:

```
mono-service /path/FileName.exe
```

as root and as a standard user, and it appears that nothing happens.

mono-service is also located in:

```
/usr/bin
```

I've searched the web and stackoverflow for answers, but haven't found anything that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution provided by **Ivan Shakhov**.

I realize that URLs to solutions are frowned on, here is the URL to the solution: http://blog.chudinov.net/demonisation-of-a-net-mono-application-on-linux/

Once I have time to test the solution, I'll post a consolidated set of instructions.